# When to use standard error and when to use unpaired t test?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, standard-error

I want to compare the mean values of two populations and understand if they are are different at a given confidence level. Two tests appear in books; the mean plus the SE of the mean and the t-test (unpaired in my case). What I cannot find is why and when you would use one and not the other. What are the guidelines, rules for using each one?

Comment: Do you have the standard error of the difference between the means or just for each of the two means?

Comment: @mdewey I have the data for both samples so I can generate the mean and SE for each one or generate the SE of the difference. The numbers in each sample are large (low 1000s) in case that affects what approximations are valid. It will probably make very small differences significant too

Comment: If you look at the formula for the independent groups t-test you will see that it consists of dividing the difference between the means by the standard error of the difference so the two courses of action you outline are effectively the same.

Answer (score 1):

The first option you list is ambiguous. There is no test that uses the "mean plus the SE of the mean". First two questions: what mean are you referring to, and what standard error?

The *t*-test takes the difference in both means and divides it by the standard error of that difference. If this result is greater than some critical value obtained from the *t*-distribution, then you have a statistically significant difference between both means.

This is essentially equivalent to multiplying the standard error of the difference by a critical value (obtained from the *t*-distribution) and adding it to the lesser mean. If the addition to the lesser mean results in a value greater than the larger mean, then you do not have a statistically significant difference. If otherwise, then you have a statistically significant difference. I hope you can see that both procedures are equivalent.

As long as you satisfy the assumptions of the t-test, you can use it. There is the *z*-test which would compare the result of dividing the mean difference by the standard error to 1.96. If the absolute value of this division is greater than 1.96, you also have statistical significance; otherwise, you don't. If one has large sample sizes as you do, both tests will give you the same result and are near identical.